# Save variable while in a "for"

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, dos

Concerning the Windows batch files: Is there a way to have a variable with all pathes leading to my folders "src" followed by *.cc, it should look like this when I print it :

```
path1\src\*.cc path2\src\*.cc etc.
```

I've found this :

```
for /d /r . %%g in (src) do echo %%g
```

but it print

```
path1\src
path2\src
etc.
```

on the standard output, because of the `echo %%g`.

***EDIT***

I need to have the result in a variable, not print on the screen (std out). It must be `path_to_folder1\*.cc path_to_folder2\*.cc [...]`.

Is it possible ?

***EDIT 2***

I'm actually with the following code :

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /d /r c:\ %%g in (Desktop*) do (
    set APLLIS_SRC= !APPLIS_SRC! %%g\*.cc
)
endlocal
```

which give me this out put if I do in the for `echo path: !APPLIS_SRC!`:

```
path:
path:
[...]
Press any key to continue...
```

So my variable is empty...
Why ?

OS: Windows Server 2008 SP2

Comment: The `setlocal` command sets a local environment. Normally, `%var%` returns the value of `var` - but within a loop, `%var%` is evaluated only once - before the the loop starts operating. The `enabledelayedexpansion` option makes `!var!` work like `%var%` but with the **run-time** value of `var`, that is, as it is changed by the loop, hence `var` accumulates the values supplied by `%%g`. The downside is that `endlocal` *or reaching end-of-file* restores the environment to its starting condition and the values appear to be unchanged outside of the `setlocal...endlocal` bracket.

Comment: It's normal to start a batch with `setlocal` in order to ensure that the environment remains "clean" - changes made by the batch don't remain in memory and contaminate the environment. If you deliberately wish to set the variable within the `cmd` instance for use by other programs, then you need to leave the `setlocal` out. The downside of that is that `enabledelayeexpansion` can't be used. The cure is to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`...(whatever your program does)...`endlocal&set var1=%var1%&set var2=%var2%` - the `set` commands being on the same physical line as the `endlocal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "myvar="
for /d /r . %%g in (src) do set "myvar=!myvar! %%g"

echo %myvar%
echo %myvar:~1%
```

(untested)

Note that 'myvar' will contain a leading space.

Comment: "The variable is empty" - what do you mean? What did the routine display?

Comment: the routine display:
`ECHO is on`
`1`

Comment: Magoo, this form of `for` doesn't work without a wildcard of some description in the search term.  As shown it will append `src` to every folder path.

Comment: @foxidrive: Certainly. That appeared to be what OP wanted - but listed in a single variable. Since the `for` switches are both `/d` and `/r` then this should build a list in a variable of the various directories named `src`. Always difficult to work with an isolated command without context.

Comment: It doesn't filter directories named src though. `for /d /r . %g in (src) do echo %g` <-- try this in a folder with subdirectories.

Comment: @foxidrive: Yes - you're correct. It's appending `\src` to **each** directoryname found. I was only concerned with building the string and used OP's codeline. `*src*` in place of `src` appears to work happily as originally intended, with the obvious "feature" of including all directorynames that **include** the character-sequence `src`

Comment: Yes.  `src?` will work fine too, or `sr?` to limit the hits, but adding `if /i "%%~nxg"=="src" echo "%%a"` with either of those two is more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

This will list the files: change both `%%g` to `%g` to use it at the cmd prompt.

```
for /r %%g in (src\*.cc) do echo "%%g"
```

Comment: I need to have the result in a variable, not print on the screen (std out). It must be `path_to_folder1\*.cc path_to_folder2\*.cc etc.`